# How can I trace performance problems in an Ubuntu / Apache / MySQL / Rails + Passenger stack?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance-monitoring

I have performance issues with a Rails stack that is running Apache 2.2.9, MySQL 5.1, Passenger 2.2.9 and Rails 2.3.8 (ruby 1.8.7-p72) on an Ubuntu 8.04 server.

How can I trace performance issues in that stack?

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try a free month of [New Relic RPM](http://newrelic.com/) service.